# Is "depending on whom of" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The curiosity you held for the future depending on whom of your
> friends you killed had manifested itself in a bloodthirsty streak.
>
> Depending on whom of these people you choose, you shall also be
> awarded 1,000$.

Depending on whom of X means the same thing as depending on who of X? I am asking, because I don't see that wording on Google often, it's almost as if it's incorrect, but maybe it's not showing up, because Google made some changes to its search engine.

Comment: The pronoun there should be "which". The whole sentence doesn't make much sense.